# Directed Sampling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to determine if anyone has attempted/done directed sampling in any field. I am having a hard time trying to determine the best way to do this, but I'll try to explain.

[image: Yield Map]

Given a yield map like above, I want to determine areas that need sampling using statistics. Basically, I want to break down this field into areas of a certain size, most likely 75-100 ft due to memory and then determine areas that need to be sampling based on the most extreme anomalies (either very high or low) and start heading toward 0 deviation.

I need to be able to control the number of points to look at, for cost reasons.
An example is below.

[image: Yield with sample points]

I realize this has many parts, but I am only asking for direction, or examples if someone has done something similar before.

Comment: your question is unclear, what determines if an area "needs" sampling?

Comment: The easiest would be to determine distance from the mean of an area (75-100 ft) I would start by sampling the furthest from the mean and work toward the mean if I have a number of points to use based on sampling costs.

Comment: so, if we consider your map a contour map, the areas that need sampling are the ones where the contour lines are closest together?

Comment: I think this is a better example... Looking at a z-score (since it goes on both sides of the curve) we have a mean of 183 bu/ac and a standard deviation of 40 bu/ac. The maximum 304 has a z-score of 3.025, the minimum yield 102 bu/ac has a z-score of -1.975. If we use the absolute value (to look at both sides of the scale equally). The higher the z-score the more important area to look at, and then going toward 0.